# I have some problems to display images in rst

Tags: restructuredtext

I just began using reStructuredText and I have some issues.
I'm using http://rst.ninjs.org/ to test my code but I didnt' succeed to import image.

piece of code:

`.. image:: C:/Users/raphael.declercq/Desktop/STAGE/rst/lab3/flow_diagram_ex2.png
    :alt: ASM flow diagram for position sensor`

On the preview I have only "ASM flow diagram for position sensor" and no image displayed.
Can someone help me?

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, "Online reStructuredText editor" can only use images available via an URL. It does not have access to your C: drive.

Comment: I suggest downloading docutils and trying out the rst2html.py script (see http://docutils.sourceforge.net/README.html#quick-start). Another option is to use Sphinx (http://www.sphinx-doc.org).

Comment: ok thanks, i will try this out :)

Comment: Spinx is what I use and I am happy with it.